# WebMethod not working when returning relatively large string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am using Virtual Basic with ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2008.  I am using Webmethod to communicate from/to the server with the client.  Data can be queried and returned in small amount, but when I try get a relatively large amount of data, it's returning me a Server 500 error.  My data is 226561 character long, so it's not that large, but it's relatively larger than my other working testing set, which are about 10k character long.

JavaScript:

```
    PageMethods.my_func("context", success);
    function success(result, userContext, methodName) {
        alert("success!");
    }
```

Failed Virtual Basic Code:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function my_func(ByVal context As String) As IEnumerable
    var result = "..."  '200k characters long
    Return result
End Function
```

Successful Virtual Basic Code:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function my_func(ByVal context As String) As IEnumerable
    var result = "..."  '10k characters long
    Return result
End Function
```

Is there anything I can change to increase WebMethod returned string length limit?  Is there even a length limit or is it some other problem I could not see?

Comment: Why are you returning a `string` as `IEnumerable`?

Comment: That's what the tutorial told me to do.  I actually do my own serialization before returning the result.  Is that redundant?

Comment: If you perform your serialization to string than declare the method as simply returning `string`, not `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that your issue may be with the [maxJsonLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength.aspx) property (more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763183.aspx)).

You can adjust this setting in web.config:

Comment: @YongkeBillYu: Many years of banging our heads against the wall with the same or similar problems.